# Removing terms of certain degree in multivariable polynomial

Tags: polynomials

I am new to *Mathematica* and I have what I am sure is a basic question, which I unfortunately have not been able to figure out. I am trying to keep terms in a polynomial that are of the same degree only. For example, if I have a polynomial in the variables `x` and `y` like the following

```
poly = ax^2*y - bx*y - cx*y^2 + dx + ey
```

what could I do to extract, for example, only the terms of third order, i.e the terms

```
ax^2*y-cx*y^2
```

Comment: Note that `ax` is a distinct entity from `a x`; if you want to multiply different variables, separate them with a space or explicitly use an asterisk.

Comment: You can extract the coefficients with `CoefficientList` and then take out the elements you want, e.g. by using `IntegerPartitions` but I'm sure there are better methods.

Comment: Related: [(126553)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/126553/extract-variable-and-coefficient-from-equation-elegantly); [(41918)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/41918/reducing-a-multi-variate-polynomial-to-have-terms-upto-certain-degree).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
poly = a x^2*y - b x*y - c x*y^2 + d x + e y;
var = {x, y};

FromCoefficientRules[Select[CoefficientRules[poly, var], Total@#[[1]] == 3 &], var]
```

> a x^2 y - c x y^2

Comment: Great, thank you so much!

Answer (score 6):

```
Tr[Select[MonomialList[poly],Tr[Exponent[#,{x,y}]]==3&]]
```

> a x^2 y-c x y^2

Answer (score 4):

Another route:

```
d = 3;
poly = a x^2*y - b x*y - c x*y^2 + d x + e y;
var = {x, y};

Fold[Dot, CoefficientArrays[poly, var][[d + 1]], ConstantArray[var, d]]
   x (a x y - c y^2)
```

Answer (score 3):

Easiest is to use a new variable to collect powers in the ones of interest, then set it to 1.

```
poly = a*x^2*y - b*x*y - c*x*y^2 + d*x + e*y;
vars = {x, y};
Coefficient[poly /. Thread[vars -> t*vars], t^3] /. t -> 1

(* Out[1086]= a x^2 y - c x y^2 *)
```