# Taking some terms from a polynomial

Tags: pattern-matching, polynomials

I have a polynomial like this:

```
ser = 1 - x/2 - x^2/8 - x^3/16 + y/2 + (3 x y)/4 + (23 x^2 y)/16 + ( 27 x^3 y)/32 - y^2/8 - (31 x y^2)/16 - (127 x^2 y^2)/64 - ( 351 x^3 y^2)/128 + y^3/16 + (35 x y^3)/32 + (407 x^2 y^3)/128 + ( 1915 x^3 y^3)/256;
```

Now I want to extract the terms with total degree smaller than 4. Using patterns, I can realize the goal.

```
Cases[ser, (_*x^m_.*y^n_. /; m + n < 5) | (_?NumericQ*y^j_. /; j < 5) | (_?NumericQ*x^i_. /; i < 5) | _?NumericQ]
```

But I think my method is a little tedious. I have two questions: 1.  can my method be simplified?  2. are there other simple methods to do the job?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use Jens's method from [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/15035):

```
expr[x_, y_] := 1 - x/2 - x^2/8 - x^3/16 + y/2 + (3 x y)/4 + (23 x^2 y)/16 + (27 x^3 y)/32 -
                y^2/8 - (31 x y^2)/16 - (127 x^2 y^2)/64 - (351 x^3 y^2)/128 + y^3/16 +
                (35 x y^3)/32 + (407 x^2 y^3)/128 + (1915 x^3 y^3)/256

expr2[x_, y_] = Normal[Series[expr[x t, y t], {t, 0, 4}]] /. t -> 1

   (* 1 + 1/2 (-x + y) + 1/8 (-x^2 + 6 x y - y^2) + 1/16 (-x^3 + 23 x^2 y - 31 x y^2 + y^3) +
   1/64 (54 x^3 y - 127 x^2 y^2 + 70 x y^3) *)
```

To obtain the OP's result

```
List @@ Expand[expr2[x, y]]

(* {1, -(x/2), -(x^2/8), -(x^3/16), y/2, (3 x y)/4, (23 x^2 y)/16, (
 27 x^3 y)/32, -(y^2/8), -((31 x y^2)/16), -(127/64) x^2 y^2, y^3/16, (
 35 x y^3)/32} *)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
Sort @ Select[Exponent[# /. y -> x, x] < 5 &] @ MonomialList[ser]

TeXForm @ %
```

> $\left\{1,-\frac{x}{2},-\frac{x^2}{8},-\frac{x^3}{16},\frac{y}{2},\frac{3 x y}{4},\frac{23 x^2 y}{16},\frac{27 x^3 y}{32},-\frac{y^2}{8},-\frac{31 x
>    y^2}{16},-\frac{127}{64} x^2 y^2,\frac{y^3}{16},\frac{35 x y^3}{32}\right\}$

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`CoefficientList`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CoefficientList.html) and select necessary items in the matrix:

```
ser = 
  1 - x/2 - x^2/8 - x^3/16 + 
   y/2 + (3 x y)/4 + (23 x^2 y)/16 + (27 x^3 y)/32 - 
   y^2/8 - (31 x y^2)/16 - (127 x^2 y^2)/64 - (351 x^3 y^2)/128 + 
   y^3/16 + (35 x y^3)/32 + (407 x^2 y^3)/128 + (1915 x^3 y^3)/256;

PolynomialQ[ser, x]
(* True *)

coef = CoefficientList[ser, {x, y}]
(* {{1, 1/2, -(1/8), 1/16}, {-(1/2), 3/4, -(31/16), 35/
  32}, {-(1/8), 23/16, -(127/64), 407/128}, {-(1/16), 27/
  32, -(351/128), 1915/256}} *)
```

List of necessary coefficients:

```
selectedCoef = Reverse@LowerTriangularize[Reverse@coef, 1]
(* {{1, 1/2, -(1/8), 1/16}, {-(1/2), 3/4, -(31/16), 35/
  32}, {-(1/8), 23/16, -(127/64), 0}, {-(1/16), 27/32, 0, 0}} *)
```

Now you can build polynomial from this coefficients:

```
coefList = Expand@Fold[FromDigits[Reverse[#1], #2] &, selectedCoef, {x, y}]
(* 1 - x/2 - x^2/8 - x^3/16 + y/2 + (3 x y)/4 + (
 23 x^2 y)/16 + (27 x^3 y)/32 - y^2/8 - (31 x y^2)/16 - (
 127 x^2 y^2)/64 + y^3/16 + (35 x y^3)/32 *)
```

To get the result in form of list:

```
Sort@MonomialList[coefList]
(* {1, -(x/2), -(x^2/8), -(x^3/16), y/2, (3 x y)/4, (
 23 x^2 y)/16, (
 27 x^3 y)/32, -(y^2/8), -((31 x y^2)/
  16), -(127/64) x^2 y^2, y^3/16, (35 x y^3)/32} *)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can adapt Yode's method from his answer to:  [Removing terms of certain degree in multivariable polynomial](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/133412/removing-terms-of-certain-degree-in-multivariable-polynomial)

```
var={x,y};
Sort@Select[MonomialList[ser], Tr[Exponent[#, var]] < 5 &]
```

> $$\left\{1,-\frac{x}{2},-\frac{x^2}{8},-\frac{x^3}{16},\frac{y}{2},\frac{3 x y}{4},\frac{23
>    x^2 y}{16},\frac{27 x^3 y}{32},-\frac{y^2}{8},-\frac{31 x y^2}{16},-\frac{127}{64} x^2
>    y^2,\frac{y^3}{16},\frac{35 x y^3}{32}\right\}$$

[N.B.: Your code gives total degree <5, while your language said "smaller than 4", so I replicated the former.]

Answer (score 2):

You could also use `CoefficientArrays`

```
v = {x, y};
c = CoefficientArrays[ser, v]
result = {c[[1]], c[[2]].v, c[[3]].v.v, c[[4]].v.v.v, c[[5]].v.v.v.v} // Expand
```

$$
\left\{1,\frac{y}{2}-\frac{x}{2},-\frac{x^2}{8}+\frac{3 x y}{4}-\frac{y^2}{8},\frac{23 x^2 y}{16}-\frac{x^3}{16}-\frac{31 x y^2}{16}+\frac{y^3}{16},-\frac{127
   x^2 y^2}{64}+\frac{27 x^3 y}{32}+\frac{35 x y^3}{32}\right\}
$$